Starter engagement
Greetings I would like to know why my starters wont engage with my torque converter on my 1971 Plymouth Roadrunner 383 automatic. My original starter off and on started going thud so I bought a remanufactured one from Rock Auto,it started car twice then thud only into converter I have inspection plate off and watched from under car. I put the one from my 1986 truck in and it works but had to take back out to install header again major night mare with my large tube headers I am old and ran out of oomph and could not hold weight of starter and my finger got smoked out and 6 stitches would still like to use reman if not a dud I would love this mystery solved for I am worried the 1986 starter will conk when I am out driving ,Thank you to all who answer.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the starter gears too close together or too far apart when trying to start the vehicle?

Distance is good as i ran the first one since 1995 till 2024 before problem started. It appears when looking from under car spinning it to see what is going on it hits inside of natural alignment and not out enough to mesh .reman aligned twice to start car first two times ran into same thud all bolts are tourqued proper and converter is hp with ballanced flex plate 2 yrs ago replaced and about 3000 miles.Thank you for responding.

It sounds as though the starter gear pops forward, engages the ring gear, but doesn't turn the engine? Other than the movement towards the ring gear, the starter doesn't do anything, correct?

A couple thoughts.  Battery, cables, grounds all good?  Check the voltage at the battery while attempting to crank.  Did you go with a known good name brand?  Lots of junk out there, especially in the Economy section on RockAuto.  Are the old, new and 86 starter the same style?  If the 71 style is a big starter, and the 86 is a smaller gear reduction starter, the gear reduction starter will always start easier with more torque.
